# Definitions of: AnsiString, WideString, String, char[], char*, BSTR,

Tags: string, char, c++builder, widestring, ansistring

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9398269/890320)

`AnsiString` is a class, too? And `string`? It is a class? And a `char[]`?

Can we say a `WideString` is a wrapper over double-byte characters, `AnsiString` is a wrapper over single-byte characters, and `char[]` is an array of single-byte characters? `string` not so sure what it is...

Not sure about the diferent kind of string types I have in Code Builder C++ 2007 available and its portability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [`AnsiString`](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol1/9708/An_AnsiString_class_reference.htm?PHPSESSID=d9bd31edf1f754a5698c2edbfcad241f) is a class provided C++ Builder,
- [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) is class provided by the C++ standard library,
- `char []` creates an array of the type of character,
- `char *` creates a pointer to the type character,
- [`BSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a Windows COM specific string class.

`AnsiString` and `BSTR` are non portable, while `std::string`, `char []` and `char*` are completely portable.

Comment: Also worth noting that System::String is an alias for AnsiString in 2007 and earlier, but UnicodeString in 2009 and later.

Comment: `WideString`, `UnicodeString`, and `std::wstring` are also classes available in C++Builder.  `WideString` (which is a wrapper for `BSTR`) and `UnicodeString` are encoded as UTF-16, but the encoding of `std::wstring` is platform-dependant as `wchar_t` is 16-bit on some platforms and 32-bit on others.